# String Encryption in Nanoframework

Tags: c#, .net, nanoframework

I am interested to understand how I can symetrically encrypt/decrypt a string in Nanoframework.

In my case the nanoframework would be deployed on an ESP32 controller. The encryption/decryption would help a .NET application running on a computer communicate with an ESP32.

I have tried searching through documentation but couldnt find anything yet.

In summary what I want to achieve is following:

```
string message = “Top Secret Message!!”;
string encryptedString = Encrypt(message, key, IV);
string decryptedMessage = Decrypt(encryptedString, key, IV);
```

Can someone guide, if such functinality is already there in NanoFramework. If not what could be a possible implememtation of the Encrypt/Dcrypt function.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no C# encryption library available in .NET nanoFramework.
The encryption capabilities already exist just that they are not exposed to C# code.
That's something in the works, which shouldn't be too far way. You can track the issue [here](https://github.com/nanoframework/Home/issues/648).

That will open up all kinds of possibilities for encryption/decryption libraries.
Out of curiosity, what algorithms you are considering?

PS: in case you want to help on this, that would be great. We love PRs! ;)